How to raise/lower half of a deck about 8"
I have a deck where one half of the deck is about 8" lower than the other half, and we just got a pavilion that is big enough to span both halves of the deck. Therefore, I'd like to make it all one height. My first thought was raising the second half, but I doubt that "stacking" joists is very safe, or up to code. Alternatively, I could lower the other half which seems a bit easier except I can't mount any lower to the house without it needing mounted to the foundation block. Any suggestions? I'd like to avoid re-setting taller posts since the deck is still very solid as-is.




Can you take a crack at a drawing from above with approximate dimensions? I bet you're going to end up rebuilding the deck and stairs.

Stacking joists is safe if done right.  You just repeat how the first row was done with nails/screws, blocking, rim joists.

@KMJ depending how big the pavilion is and its orientation, OP could simply leave a landing at the top of the stairs.

Put blocks between the feet of the pavilion and the lower portion of the deck. This will require the minimum additional work and expense, and give you added head room over the lower portion of the deck. The blocking could be (should be) attached to the joists so that it doesn't move, but should otherwise have almost zero impact on the existing deck structure.
